# Rails: grabbing child class params in partial view for bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, associations, bootstrap-modal

In my rails app, I'm rendering a partial via a bootstrap modal.

This partial contains the index for the class' child's (has_many) class

In my index.html.erb for the parent class - Costs - a button to call the modal sending the appropriate instance and then the modal itself.

Button:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>'.html_safe, "/costs/#{cost.id}/cost_dependencies", {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window', :class => 'btn btn-warning', :cost => cost.id} %>
```

And then the model (the `Costs.first` is to remedy the `nilClass` error)

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <%= render 'costs/dependency_index', :locals => {:cost => Cost.first} %>   
    </div>
  </div>
```

and then the partial for the modal itself:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  <h3 id="myModalLabel">Dependencies</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= locals.first[1].cost_dependencies.each do |d| %> 
    <%= d.dependency_category %>
  <%end%> %>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  Testing
</div>
```

As of now I know that the `locals.first[1]` retrieves the Cost instance, but I cannot access `cost_dependencies` from there.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:** my Cost Model:

```
class Cost < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :cost_dependency

    validates :per_job, numericality: true
    validates :per_page, numericality: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cost_dependency

end
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?  And what does your cost model look like?

Comment: I'm getting a `undefined method 'cost_dependencies' for #<Cost:0x007fd7216f2138>` error, and the model I will edit the question to put that there

Comment: You have declared the relation as `has_many :cost_dependency` not `has_many :cost_dependencies`.

Comment: It should also be `accepts_nested_attributes_for :cost_dependencies`

Comment: Doing `locals.first[1]` is pretty hacky - just reference the local `cost`.

Comment: I am new to associations. does the cost_dependency db table need cost.id as a column? because now I'm receiving a `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: cost_dependencies.cost_id: SELECT "cost_dependencies".* FROM "cost_dependencies" WHERE "cost_dependencies"."cost_id" = ?` error

Comment: That being said, you were right about the `cost_dependency` vs `cost_dependencies` thing, so thank you very much for that

Comment: It was that, I just had to add cost_id to the Cost_dependencies table. it is all good now

Comment: As Max said, you should use locals only when you use :template => "". Either `= render 'costs/dependency_index', :cost => Cost.first` or `= render :template => 'costs/dependency_index', :locals => {:cost => Cost.first}`.

Comment: In the partial, access `cost`, don't access `locals`. You can access `local_assigns` if you need to.

Comment: And, another small thing - don't use the equals `=` with `.each` in the partial. just a `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found in the Comments on the question itself.

My model was saying I had a `has_many :cost_dependency` when it should have been a `has_many :cost_dependencies`

I had to pluralize it, and I also forgot to add the `cost_id` column to my `cost_dependencies` table